# How does rolling resistance of rail wheel depend on diameter?

Tags: friction

Freight train is more efficient than truck due to lower [rolling resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance). And I wonder which one has lower rolling resistance<>, small diameter or larger one or it doesn't not depend on diameter at all? Both are steel wheel on steel rail.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it? Since wikipedia has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance#Physical_formulas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the Wikipeda article on [rolling resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance#Physical_formulas) that @fibonatic pointed out, you can find an equation for the coefficient of rolling friction:

$C_{rr}=\sqrt {\frac z d}$

There is another equation after it that is for steel on steel, but that also shows that C is proportional to $d^{-\frac 1 2}$.  So from this, you can easily see that a smaller diameter will have a higher C, and thus a higher resistance.    A freight train will have a larger diameter than a truck, meaning less resistance, thus being more efficient.